# Notice: Use of undefined constant OK - assumed 'OK'

Tags: php

I'm getting this warning message,

> "Notice: Use of undefined constant OK - assumed 'OK'"

I've tried both `"OK"` and `'OK'`, but both of them triggers the warning.

Also, I only get this error on the server and not locally.

```
<?php
$post_data = http_build_query(
    array(
        'email' => $_GET['email'],
    )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $post_data
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
if ($_GET['email']) {
    $response = file_get_contents('https://url.delibr.com/webhooks/example', false, $context);
    if ($response == "OK") {
        echo $_GET['email'] . " has received an invite!";
    } else {
        echo "Unknown error!" . $response;
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: only `OK` would cause that; `'OK'` and `"OK"` are strings, `OK` is a constant

Comment: Using the above code I am unable to reproduce that error

Comment: As others have said, this code won't generate that error, it must be coming from somewhere else.